# Filter product by button of products in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using eCommerce Product catalog plugin.
I want to make a dropdown of category when i click on dropdrown show all products list of subcategory

I don't know how to make dropdown of ajax in wordpress on which file i will change in code or add code so that i can make this dropdown display product on same page
so please suggest me

Comment: Can you share us the plugin documentation or code?

Comment: plugin in WordPress-: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ecommerce-product-catalog/
Plugin Documentation https://implecode.com/docs/ecommerce-product-catalog/getting-started/